# Python, if statements on loops

Tags: python, if-statement

I am having an issue exluding some data from my python script, beginner learning here!

Currently I have a csv file with c. 19 columns, I need to print col 0, 1, 8, 18 - which I have successfully.

Column 8, has a value of 0.00, or above. I would like the script to exclude these lines and not print them. I have attempted the if statement, but the below code just executes and prints all lines - doesnt only print those 0.01 or above.

Current code:

```
import csv

m = open('data.csv')
csv_m = csv.reader(m)

for row in csv_m:
        if row[8] >= 1:
                print(row[0],row[1],row[8],row[18],)
```

Comment: First index of a list is row[0] (0 indexed).  Try row[7].

Comment: Isn't there any error occurred? The data which are read from csv are `str` type. So you cannot compare with `int` directly. Try `float(row[8]) >= 1`

Comment: You say "0.01 or above" in the description, but your code says .```>=1```

Comment: the code days >=1 as I was simply trying to get it to work. As printed, no error is defined but all rows print.

Answer (score 1):

csv data are always strings, and `"1"` (string) will never compare equal to `1` (int) or `0.01` (float). You need to either explicitely turn your csv data into the appropriate type (using `int(row[8])` or `float(row[8])` or, much more simply, compare with the string representation of your target value, if:

```
if row[8] == "1": # or "0.01"
   # etc
```

Also, you want to 1/ open your file in binary mode (python2) or with the `newline=''` argument (python3) and 2/ use a `with` statement to make sure your file will be closed whatever happens:

```
# py3 version
with open("yourfile.csv", newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row[8] > "0.01":
            print(row[0],row[1],row[8],row[18])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

> with open('file', 'mode') as file:

this will ensure that the file will be closed at the end of the operation. It is a python good practise.

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as file:  
  for row in file: 
    if row[8] >= 1.0 :
      print(row)
```

You should post a example of the csv file to make it clear. **Check the format of the row, maybe you will have to convert it to float before comparing**.

You have the option of using pandas since this is a csv

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

filter = data[8] >= 1
filtered_data = data[filter]

for index, row in filtered_data.iterrows():
  print (row[0],row[1],row[8],row[18])
```

Comment: why is everyone insisting on using panda when it's not needed ?

Comment: because its simple for beginners

Comment: I don't think a 800 pounds lib is simpler than a simple csv module, and it's better for a beginner to understand the basics (in this case that it's not because a string is made of numeric characters that it's a numeric) than to use convoluted solutions.

Answer (score -2):

This can be easily done if you are willing to use the Pandas library.

You can try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

good_data = data[data[data.columns[8]] >= 0.01]

print(good_data.iloc[:, [0, 1, 8, 18]])
```

Comment: No need for panda here.